# Android IAB Error RPC:S-7 AEC-0

Tags: android, error-handling, in-app-purchase

I made an app with In-app billing, tested it and published it without any problem at all. The in-app purchase worked.
Now i'm doing an update with a new in-app purchase and can't buy anything with my new update, Play Store purchase fragment always give me this message:

```
Error while retrieving informations from server [RPC:S-7:AEC-0]
```

Logcat gives me this error:

```
02-12 12:15:27.524: E/Volley(5650): [629] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for https://android.clients.google.com/fdfe/commitPurchase
02-12 12:15:27.539: D/Finsky(5650): [1] PurchaseFragment.handleError: Error: PurchaseError{type=2 subtype=0}
```

The Play Store app has the same versionCode as the one i'm developping, and my test account is the first account on the phone. THe in-app item is already been published and active.
I tried deleting my test account and readding it, cleasing data and cache from Google Play Services and Play Store, even with other users it gives the same error.
Please help me, i really don't know what to do.

Comment: I am struggling with exactly the same problem for a couple of hours, still no luck. Done pretty much everything I could find on the internet, even most ridiculous tips.

Comment: It happened to us too. After couple of hours it started working again...

Answer (score 0):

It was a temporary Google Play error...
I did nothing at all, yesterday it didn't work,but now it works.

Comment: You should also mention how to reproduce this error and how you solved it, i.e. the actions taken to realise that "it was a temporary error...".